# Show category-ID in custom category-list

Tags: categories

I created a category-list to show them in a way, my accordion can use. (Custom in the sidebar) I want to add a class named "current"  for the currently viewed post and the viewed category should be opened. Do you have any ideas to integrate this in the code? It was hard work to get this to work and now I dont know how to integrate it...

Link: http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/anna-bederke-actor/ (after you click "Portfolio", the menu appears and should show the opened tree with a highlighted post.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="category-list">
    <ul class="topnav"> 
        <?php
        $kategorien = get_categories(array(
        'child_of' => 0,
        'exclude_tree' => 15,
        'exclude' => 16,
        'orderby' => 'slug',
        'order' => 'ASC')); 
            foreach($kategorien as $kategorie) { 
            echo '<li><a href="#" class="category-title">'; echo ($kategorie->name); echo '</a>';
                echo '<ul>';
                    $cat = $kategorie->cat_ID;
                    $posts = get_posts('category='. $cat .'&posts_per_page=-1');
                        foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        <li>
                    <? }
                echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
            } 
        ?>                  
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="category-list">
    <ul class="topnav"> 
        <?php
        if (is_single()){
            global $post;
            $pid = $post->ID;
            $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
            $cats = array();
            foreach($post_categories as $c){
                $cat = get_category( $c );
                $cats[] = $cat->ID;
            }
            $active_cat_count = true;
            $cat_count = 0;
        }

        $kategorien = get_categories(array(
        'child_of' => 0,
        'exclude_tree' => 15,
        'exclude' => 16,
        'orderby' => 'slug',
        'order' => 'ASC')); 
            foreach($kategorien as $kategorie) { 
            if (isset($active_cat_count) && $active_cat_count){
                if (in_array($kategorie->ID,$cats){
                    $active_cat_count = false;
                }else{
                    $cat_count = $cat_count + 1;
                }
            }
            echo '<li><a href="#" class="category-title">'; echo ($kategorie->name); echo '</a>';
                echo '<ul>';
                    $cat = $kategorie->cat_ID;
                    $posts = get_posts('category='. $cat .'&posts_per_page=-1');
                        foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                        <li>
                            <a <?php if ($post->ID == $pid){echo 'class="current"';} ?> href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        <li>
                    <? }
                echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
            } 
        ?>                  
    </ul>
</div>
<?php
if (is_single()){
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".topnav" ).accordion( "option", "active", <?php echo $cat_count; ?> );
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Link: http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/anna-bederke-actor/

Mh, doesnt work!
Whats this at the end?
<?php
}

Comment: the `<?php }` at the end is to close the final if statement, as for why its not working' i can't see the code there so i can't tell. let me know when you use that code and i'll take a look.

Comment: Its online now (previous link)!

Comment: I don't see the JavaScript is this a custom post type or a regular single post view?

Comment: Its a custom post type: Heres the javascript

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".topnav").accordion({
   header: 'a.category-title',
   accordion:true,
   speed: 500,
   closedSign: '+',
   openedSign: '-'
  });
 });

Comment: ok then if its a custom post type change `is_single()` to `is_singular('CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME')` in both cases

Comment: Sadly it says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '(' in /homepages/11/d120350608/htdocs/2011/wp-content/themes/davidgoltz/sidebar.php on line 5 and thats the line with the is_singular

Comment: Create a pastebin of your code

Comment: Heres the pastebin of the code: http://pastebin.com/B7cqZRiY

Comment: you mist something , try this: http://pastebin.com/v1yv8cBS

Comment: Unexpected { in line 26 :-( http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/pickers/

Comment: i posted the answer as an example to get you started, i can't fix ever bit of syntax error for you, simple missing `)` http://pastebin.com/5C5ca8KS